# Start up with a solid background color

Tags: java, android

I want my app to start up with a black background.
As of now, when the app starts the screen appears white then changes to black in the flash of an eye.
How do I make it start up with a black background in the first place?

I tried setting the background color in the layout file:

```
android:background="@color/black"
```

I also tried setting the background color in the activity's onCreate method:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Both methods have the same effect (app starts up with a white background then quickly changes to black).

Comment: Maybe try using `android:windowDisablePreview="true"`, to disable the initial blank screen?

Comment: Also see https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#java

Comment: Set the window background color in the theme. Don't bother setting it in the layout. Not sure, but this might cause it to be drawn twice, which is wasteful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try in your app theme:

```
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```